# Reference to generic derived class only specifying some of the type parameters causes "incompatible types" error from compiler

Tags: java, generics

Why does the compiler report an error for the following code?

```
class B<T, U> {
  T t; U u;
  public B(T t, U u) { this.t = t; this.u = u; }
  public T getT() { return t; }
  public U getU() { return u; }
}
class D<T> extends B<T, String> {
  public D(T t, String u) {
    super(t, u);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  D<Integer> d1 = new D<Integer>(1, "1");
  String s1 = d1.getU();  // This line compiles
  D d2 = new D<Integer>(1, "1");
  String s2 = d2.getU();  // This line makes the compiler complain that getU returns Object and s2 is String
}
```

Why doesn't the last line work? I'd understand if getT() didn't work, as that type parameter isn't specified in s2's type. But getU will *always* return a String...

Comment: Read up on raw types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with generics, method parameters, return types, and generic types are all resolved or inferred from the method invocation of the compile time type of the reference .

When you have

```
D<Integer> d1 = new D<Integer>(1, "1");
String s1 = d1.getU();  // This line compiles
```

The compiler knows that `d1` is of type `D<Integer>`. It also resolves the return type of `d1.getU()` to `String` from its supertype.

However, when using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the
>   erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of its
>   parameterized invocations.

So `getU()` appears as

```
public Object getU()
```

when working with a reference of raw type `D`.